# Why is a 64TB drive only for Mac?

Tags: hard-drive

For reasons that I won't get into, I am stuck with Windows. I was looking for a drive and on eBay I saw a lot of 64TB drives (is there such a thing, or is it a scam?), but they were marked "or Mac only".

1. Are they real.
2. Is there any way to use them with Windows?

Comment: I'd guess it's about market more than limitations. We cannot answer your first question because you haven't given us enough info, and have you done any research on your own regarding connecting large drives to Windows?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/308492/is-there-a-size-limit-on-external-usb-hard-drives

Comment: There are legit 100TB drives. They are very special purpose, and they cost $40,000, and they've actually be around for several years.

Comment: In theory there *are* mac only drives, but those are internal

Comment: Also is this a USB C drive? I know these are fake - https://twitter.com/JourneymanGeek/status/1449212833455955972 was me documenting the one I bought to investigate, and its 2 drives that lie about their size in a USB hub

Comment: I wouldn't trust eBay to sell anything but fake 64TB drives. A [30.72TB SSD is "only" £5,000](https://www.lambda-tek.com/Kioxia-KCMYXRUG30T7~sh/B47856534) so 64TB isn't out of the realms of possibility, but if it is anything less than £10,000 it is almost certainly a scam. There are [plenty of scam drives that claim ludicrous capacities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa4mZcoc0w4) on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rule of thumb is "If its too good to be true, it is"

TLDR:

No, its fake, and while you *could* reformat them, chances are it'll fail if you do.

I recall *some* Mac models in the past used to use non standard m.2 drives, which didn't get anywhere near that big, and the largest M.2 drive you can get at the moment is around 4TB. There *are* u.2 or other server centric flash storage of that size for eyewateringly high prices for *servers*, and Apple dosen't really make 'servers'.

No current mac model seems to do sata, which can get you up to 18tb *a disk* at 3.5 inches.

That said, various dubious chinese vendors are happy to sell you flash storage that lies about its capacity. I bought a 4tb one to take apart (and nothing else!). They're often a pair of USB keys or SD cards with firmware that claim larger capacities than they do, and they fail when you actually try to test them. Sometimes they even have a little extra weight.

[image]

I'd guess the "Mac only" label lets them stick on a price premium - or gives excuses should it not work. I've also had sellers sell me a 'fake' 1tb sd card, then claim they shipped exactly what was advertised. It *was* cheap and I bought it to test if it was fake so... I wouldn't buy it trusting that I'd get a refund either.